# textfield Mask and validation [Swift]

Tags: cosmicmind

mask validation textfield, can anyone help me with this? I am creating a registration form, and is difficult to make validations.

I need

- PhoneNumber
- DateOfBirth
- Credit Card fields

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing this manually. In the cosmic mind documentation they have demos using storyboards. I have followed these and placed IBActions in my ViewController swift code. Essentially you just place a label and assign it the class of  TextField from the Material module. In swift, I have this for example for a username field:

```
@IBAction func userNameModified(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(sender.text!.characters.count < 6) {
    userNameField.detail = "must be at least 6 characters"
    }else if (sender.text!.characters.count > 20){
        userNameField.detail = "must be less then 20 characters"
    } else {
        userNameField.detail = ""
    }

}
```

I was looking for a validator library as I want to also detect if it contains symbols, and came across this: [SwiftValidators Library](https://github.com/gkaimakas/SwiftValidators)

They seem to have most of the fields you want to validate, credit card, phone number, dates, as well as many others. I am hoping to test if this works later today/tomorrow.